# Codeigniter view not loading correctly

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to create an events management site using codeigniter, but I'm having trouble getting a search feature working correctly.

Here is the search function on the Events controller

```
public function search()
{
    $keyword = $this->input->post('keyword');
    $data['events'] = $this->event_model->get_events_by_keyword($keyword);

    $this->session->set_flashdata('event_search', 'Showing all results relating to '.$keyword);

    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('events/search', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
```

And here is the function to get the events in the event model

```
public function get_events_by_keyword($keyword)
{
    $this->db->order_by('events.date', 'ASC');

    $this->db->like('name', $keyword)
    ->or_like('location', $keyword)
    ->or_like('genre', $keyword)
    ->or_like('date', $keyword);
    $query = $this->db->get('events');

    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Currently I have 2 views, 'events/index.php' and 'events/search.php'.
The search function works perfectly fine when used from the search page, but when used from the index page, nothing happens. The page just reloads.

```
<section id="events-page">
    <form action="<?php site_url('events/search'); ?>" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="keyword" placeholder="search" required autofocus>
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row center-xs center-sm center-md center-lg">
            <?php foreach($events as $event) : ?>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 events-page-content"> 
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                            <a href="<?php echo site_url('/events/'.$event['slug']); ?>">
                                <img src="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/assets/images/events/<?php echo $event['event_image']; ?>">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                            <a href="<?php echo site_url('/events/'.$event['slug']); ?>">
                            <h3><?php echo $event['name']; ?></h3>
                            <small>Location: <?php echo $event['location']; ?></small><br>
                            <small>Genre: <?php echo $event['genre']; ?></small><br>
                            <small>Date: <?php echo $event['date']; ?></small></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>   
                </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Both views are exactly the same so I'm unsure why the search function only works correctly on one of the views. I assume it would be a route issue but I'm unsure on how to resolve this.
Ideally I don't need both views as they are exactly the same so I tried changing the search function on the events controller to this so as to just load the events page with the new data but it still has no effect and the page just reloads and stays as is.

```
public function search()
{
    $keyword = $this->input->post('keyword');
    $data['events'] = $this->event_model->get_events_by_keyword($keyword);

    $this->session->set_flashdata('event_search', 'Showing all results relating to '.$keyword);

    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('events/index', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
```

Hopefully someone on here will be able to help, cheers.

Comment: And you are 100% sure the views are **exactly** the same?

Comment: Yea I copied and pasted the code, only difference is the name of the file

Comment: A couple other weird things. I tried copying the search bar and using it in another view and the exact same thing happened, it just refreshed the page without submitting any data, only seems to work on the search view. Also, even after changing the search function to load the 'events/index' view, it's behaviour hasn't changed at all, and will still work normally in the search view and never even attempt to load the index view

Answer (score 0):

do var_dump() on the $data before you load the views.
and compare the result for that two views.

Comment: I tried this, nothing was shown when using var_dump() on the events/index but it did show data when used from events/search, unsure why

Answer (score 0):

Code looks fine. there aare some improvements mentioned below.

Please use a different variable for displaying message instead of flashing session data

Please share the complete controller so i can assist you better.

```
public function search()
{
    $keyword = $this->input->post('keyword');
    $data['events'] = $this->event_model->get_events_by_keyword($keyword);
    // you can also use javascript or jquery to display this message 
    // no need to send this back from server and make this request ajax
    $data['message'] = "Showing all results relating to $keyword";

    // $this->session->set_flashdata('event_search', 'Showing all results relating to '.$keyword);

    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('events/index', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');

}
```

Comment: Okay thanks I'll take those into account. Out of curiosity how come I shouldn't user set_flashdata()?

Comment: you can use that.
but there is no need, neither there is any compulsion.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
```

into your index.php file to check search result available into your view file.